# node-telegram-bot-api deprecated Automatic enabling of cancellation of promises is deprecated

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to create a Telegram bot but when I run the code I get these errors:

"node-telegram-bot-api deprecated Automatic enabling of cancellation of promises is deprecated
In the future, you will have to enable it yourself.
See https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/319. internal\modules\cjs\loader.js:1063:30"

"error: [polling_error] {"code":"ETELEGRAM","message":"ETELEGRAM: 409 Conflict: terminated by
other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running"}"

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my bot.js code if that helps:

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const axios = require('axios');

const parser = require('./parser.js');
 
require('dotenv').config();
 
const token = process.env.TELEGRAM_TOKEN;
let bot;
 
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
   bot = new TelegramBot(token);
   bot.setWebHook(process.env.HEROKU_URL + bot.token);
} else {
   bot = new TelegramBot(token, { polling: true });
}
 // Matches "/word whatever"
bot.onText(/\/word (.+)/, (msg, match) => {
   const chatId = msg.chat.id;
   const word = match[1];
   axios
     .get(`${process.env.OXFORD_API_URL}/entries/en-gb/${word}`, {
       params: {
         fields: 'definitions',
         strictMatch: 'false'
       },
       headers: {
         app_id: process.env.OXFORD_APP_ID,
         app_key: process.env.OXFORD_APP_KEY
       }
     })
     .then(response => {
       const parsedHtml = parser(response.data);
       bot.sendMessage(chatId, parsedHtml, { parse_mode: 'HTML' });
     })
     .catch(error => {
       const errorText = error.response.status === 404 ? `No definition found for the word: <b>${word}</b>` : `<b>An error occured, please try again later</b>`;
       bot.sendMessage(chatId, errorText, { parse_mode:'HTML'})
     });
 });
```

Comment: Regarding the deprecation warning, you could add `process.env.NTBA_FIX_319 = 1;` to the top of your file. See https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/540 .

Comment: And what about the fix? What is the future proof solution?

Answer (score 1):

- Install this package npm I dotenv
- Create a file called `.env` at the root of your project.
- Add to that file this `NTBA_FIX_319=1`
- Add to the top of your index.js file (or whatever file that contains your bot instance): `require('dotenv').config()`
- Restart your bot.
- So your code will look like

---

```
require('dotenv').config();

const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');

// replace the value below with the Telegram token you receive from @BotFather
const token = 'YOUR_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN';

// Create a bot that uses 'polling' to fetch new updates
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

bot.on('message', (msg) => {
  const chatId = msg.chat.id;

  // send a message to the chat acknowledging receipt of their message
  bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Received your message');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1) Get rid of the promise cancellation warning

The simplest, is to add that line at the top of your bot file:

```js
process.env.NTBA_FIX_319 = 1 // this line SHOULD be above all imports

const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api')

// ...rest of your telegram bot code
```

---

### 2) The 409 conflict error

In short, there are two version of your telegram bot running at the same time, so:

- check if there is not multiple instance of your server running your bot, which can be the case when using workers, pm2...
- check that your bot script is not started twice

Other causes and explanations can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69870914/conflict-terminated-by-other-getupdates-request-make-sure-that-only-one-bot-in) and [here](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/550)